# How to make a file path compatible with an embedded database? (Apache Derby Embedded)

Tags: java, database, path, derby, embedded-database

Recently I've been trying to use a JFileChooser to select where a database will be created; however, the problem I've run into is that the file path that I got from the JFileChooser has it has backslashes instead of forward slashes, and I think that this is what isn't allowing me to create the database. Here is my code, and attempt at solving the problem.

```
        try {
            // Try to connect to the database 
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver());
            databaseconnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:"+formattedfolderpath+";");
            databaseconnection.setAutoCommit(false);
            currentdb = true;
        } catch (SQLException EX) {
           try {
                // Create the DB if it doesn't exist yet 
                DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver());
                databaseconnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:"+formattedfolderpath+";create=true"); 
                databaseconnection.setAutoCommit(false);
                currentdb = true;
            } catch (SQLException EX2) {
                //infoBox("OH MY LAWD", "Error");
            }
```

and

```
    JButton open = new JButton();
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("C:/Users/1jenningst/Desktop"));
    fc.setDialogTitle("PDF Manager");
    fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    
    if (fc.showOpenDialog(open) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        //
    }
    
    String folderpath = fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
    
    try{
        formattedfolderpath = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(folderpath));
    } catch (Exception e){
        //
    }
       
    selecting();
}
```

Anyone have any ideas on how I could use a variable to complete the file path using a JFileChooser? 
Thanks, 
Michael

Comment: I am pretty sure that Derby will handle either directory separator convention (forward slash or backward slash). Are you certain that that slashes are the problem? Can you add more debugging to your program (and include the output) to help verify that, and rule other problems out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, 
I just needed to add two backslashes to the file path, instead of one:

```
C\users\missouri\desktop\123
```

becomes

```
C\\users\\missouri\\desktop\\123
```

Hope this helps, 
Trevor